# Xcode Swift Package Manager fails to use correct SSH Key for git

Tags: xcode, git, ssh

I'm trying to add the Swift Package OAuth2, but it has a submodule that declares its URL to use the HTTPS protocol. I much prefer the SSH protocol because I don't even have to think about what permissions my GitHub access token needs to have plus I haven't found those documented. ANYWAYS

This shouldn't be a problem because I have this in my `~/.gitconfig`

```
 [url "ssh://git@github.com/"]
     insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

So all https git requests automatically convert to SSH. HOWEVER, Xcode doesn't seem to use the same SSH key I have configured to pull the root repository. Plus, I have my SSH config to use a specific key and user when connecting to the `github.com` domain.

```
 host github.com
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_por_la_github
  User myself
```

Why then do I get an access error "public key" when downloading the submodule using Swift Package Manager?

The Swift Package in question is https://github.com/p2/OAuth2

Answer (score 2):

One work around is to use `ssh-agent` as follows:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_por_la_github
open myproj.xcodeproj
```

This populates your particular terminal with environment variables SSH can use to connect using an open socket on ssh-agent. Anything on your computer can connect to that socket and use your ssh key for whatever it wants to so it's not great!

Also, you have to start XCode from the same terminal where you start the ssh agent.

You can stop the agent via:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -k)
```